# Laravel delete record in relations tables on basis of same id

Tags: php, laravel

Basically i have three tables, sms_content, sms_content_cities and sms_content_categories.

I want to delete record from sms_content table, by deleting record from sms_content table record should be deleted from sms_content_cities and sms_content_categories tables .

Here is my code:

```
$smsContentCategory = SmsContentCategories::where('sms_content_id', $id)->first();
        $smsContentCategory->delete();

        $smsContentCities = SmsContentCity::where('sms_content_id', $id)->first();

        foreach ($smsContentCities as $city){
            if(!empty($city)){
                $city->delete();
            }
        }

        $model = SmsContent::find($id);
        $model->delete();
```

I am using singel category and multiple cities.

How can i delet related records.

Comment: You might want to do this on [database level](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)

Comment: You should set up cascading relations on your tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
SmsContentCategories::where('sms_content_id', $id)->delete();

SmsContentCity::where('sms_content_id', $id)->delete();

SmsContent::where('id', $id)->delete();
```

Comment: @hmrneves Why delete manually when you can take advantage of the constraints?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use foreach for it.

```
SmsContentCategories::where('sms_content_id', $id)->delete();
SmsContentCity::where('sms_content_id', $id)->delete();
SmsContent::find($id)->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete only parent model.

```
SmsContent::find($id)->delete();
```

For the child tables `sms_content_cities` and `SmsContentCategories`, add a `ON DELETE CASCADE` condition which would automatically delete rows from these child tables the moment the parent row gets deleted. You can create 2 new **migration**  files and add this constraint in each of them and do **php artisan migrate**.

```
$table->foreign('sms_content_id')->references('id')->on('sms_content')->onDelete('cascade');
```

[Laravel docs for on delete cascade](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).

Comment: I expect that the cities and categories are the parents here

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 How come? Not sure how OP has designed it, but presumably cities and categories won't come without sms content existing first.

Comment: Purely from the table names you'd expect that cities and categories are a way of grouping these contents and that all contents would reference a category and a city

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 It really depends on how you want to logically connect the tables. I would rather make a sms content and then add it's city and it's category. Anyways, clarifying from OP as to how his DB design looks like.

Comment: @FaisalKhan Is `sms_content` the parent table or are `sms_content_cities` and `sms_content_categories` the parent tables?

Comment: Why? What if you have 3 SmsContents, all in Amsterdam, you don't want 3 duplicate records of SmsCity all for Amsterdam, databases should be normalised: https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 I do know NF in DB. The data inside an sms would be different. So, it would have to be associated with a city and a category. Where is redundancy? Multiple contents could belong to same city and category and it's valid.

Comment: correct, making cities and categories the parents of contents

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 Yes,but now that I rethink, maybe all 3 can be potential parents with a 4th pivot table having content_id, city_id and category_id. This seems to make it more flexible if a content belongs to more than 1 category or city.